# Send value of dictionary to text box - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

I have a dictionary I am working with. The values of this dictionary have to then be sent using Selenium to a specific textbox in a website. I want to use a `for` loop so that it can iterate through the dictionary until finished.

Here is my sample code:

```
d = {'hello': 4.56, 'bye bye': 3.21}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Dtoro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\chromedriver.exe")
Chrome = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://justnotepad.com/")

for key, value in d.items():
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "editable_text").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    actions.send_keys(value)
```

In the above code, just `4.56 3.21` would be printed.
I've tried doing `print(value)` and that didn't work. I also tried `actions.send_keys(Keys.v)` and that didn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only sending value, as per the code - `actions.send_keys(value)`.

Try like this and confirm.

```
d = {'hello': 4.56, 'bye bye': 3.21}

driver.get("https://justnotepad.com/")

for key,value in d.items():
    textbox = driver.find_element(By.ID,"editable_text")
    textbox.send_keys(f"{key}:{value}\n") # Remove "\n" if the text should appear in a single line.
```

Comment: This worked, I really appreciate it.
For my understanding, what does the (f"{value}") do exactly? Just so I can use it in the future.

Comment: @datoro - That's formatting. You can search for `python f string`.  Used when we need to include a variable in a string. We can also replace that line with - `key + ":" + value` or `"{0}:{1}".format(key,value)`.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your help!!